# TFS: Get latest causes slow project reloading

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2015

We're working with a solution which has multiple projects which references NuGet packages from other solutions.

Every time we do get latest from the TFS server on the solution, Visual Studio (2015) starts reloading each project in the solution which takes a really long time. Now this wasn't always the case, since this started happening only a few weeks back (the solution is a year old).

We have other solutions which were already experiencing this problem and our solution is to close the solution, then do get latest, then reload the project  which is much, much faster.

Can anybody explain why this is happening and how to fix this issue?

Comment: The exact same thing is happening to me and I've had to resort to the same workaround.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: @EJoshuaS unfortunately no. The workaround provided above is the only thing that works and Microsoft doesn't seem to care (see answer)... :(

Comment: Yeah, it does seem like they don't have much interest in actually fixing this issue.

Answer (score 2):

This has been reported as a bug to MSFT, see [Slow project reloading](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1034317/slow-project-reloading) &  [Reload of projects is slow after call to TFS to get latest changeset](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/788468/reload-of-projects-is-slow-after-call-to-tfs-to-get-latest-changeset). It seems your project files are updated from outside VS, which causes VS to load all them. More details please see the reply from VS IDE team:

> Main culprit is, **your project files are being updated from outside
>   VS**, **which causes VS to load each of them one by one**. This is
>   extremely taxing process and it happens on the main UI thread. Hence,
>   this ASL logic is on-by-default to alleviate unresponsive solution
>   loads. Essentially, you’re pointing out a limitation in our ASL logic
>   that we hadn’t considered. This will be considered for a future
>   release, thank you.
>
> In the meantime, **one way to mitigate the problem would be to force
>   solution reload by touching the solution file, the `*.sln` file, which
>   will trigger ASL to kick in, basically VS thinking you’re doing full
>   solution load and it will optimize responsiveness time as much as
>   possible.**
>
> *Ulzii Luvsanbat*
>
> Visual Studio IDE Team

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Patrick. The bugs you are referring to are both closed as "not reproducable" and "not going to fix". The solution you are mentioning isn't a proper fix; it's the same type of fix I was mentioning myself (and I like mine better, since I don't want to touch files that don't need to be touched). So there is nothing you guys are doing about this issue (bugs were reported 3 years ago)? Seems like it's a pretty major thing when it comes to user experience.

Answer (score 1):

Please try these steps:

1. Open Visual Studio installer and install the most recent available update for 2017 version.
2. Open `%localappdata%/Microsoft/Team Foundation/7.0/cache` and delete all files, then restart Visual Studio and retry.