# Visual Studio takes 20 seconds to break on exception

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

hoping someone can help me. Recently my Visual Studio 2015 started to take a very long time when it encounters unhandled exception - full 20 seconds before debugger breaks and shows me where the problem is. I tried cleaning up cache, user folders, completely reinstalling visual studio, different runtime (I was using dot.net 4.6.2) with no luck. I am using VS 2015 ultimate on windows 10, running WPF project targeting 4.6.2 (I tried a very simple project with just one button to make sure it's not my solution and got same result).  When this happens, Visual Studio is not responsive. Any ideas are greatly appreciated - planning to wipe my computer clean because not sure what else I can try. Thank you

Comment: Do you have alot of watches in the watches window? Try turning off "Call string conversion" in the debugging options (that speeds up mine).  And before you wipe your machine, try repairing / uninstalling - reinstalling visual studio first

Comment: There is no Ultimate Edition for 2015, there only is Professional, Enterprise, and community editions. Also, 2015 has a very nice "report a issue" feature that can do a trace on visual studio. If you record a trace and submit the issue to Microsoft you can often get responses and help, I have in the past.

Comment: I don't have any watches at all - I will look into call string conversion, thanks. you are correct, I am running enterprise, not ultimate. I have already reinstalled Visual Studio twice, remove all the extensions, uninstalled dot.net 4.6.2 so far with no results

Comment: Turn of your antivirus program if it is running. I have sometimes trouble with the latest trend micro version

Comment: I use microsoft's defender and malware bytes. Both of those have never slowed anything down. I did end up wiping my pc clean and reinstalling everything. When I got it back up and running, VS would break to an exception in about 9 seconds. That's terrible. My laptop is a monster (xeon cpu, 32gb ram, ssd, etc....). I found out all my other laptops were doing under 2 seconds. After playing with settings, I found there is one setting that made a difference - exception assistant. Turning it off results in instant VS break on exception. Turning it back own slows it down.

Comment: The interesting thing is after toggling it on/off, the vs now breaks in about second and a half (down from 9 seconds before I toggled that setting). At this point I blame my problem on Visual Studio, not my settings or my computer.

Comment: Just to take a wild stab at it, how big is your solution file? Large solution files have [caused performance problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40471914/visual-studio-2015-takes-10-15-minutes-to-reload-projects-after-a-get-latest) for me under certain circumstances. Again, I'm taking a stab at it, but it might be worth checking.

Comment: Incidentally, can you add your comments as an answer for the benefit of future readers?

Answer (score 1):

The answer in my case was definitely exception assistant. Having that option turned on slows down entering break mode in Visual Studio. I found out in my case that toggling the exception off and back on improved VS breaking from 9 seconds to 2 seconds (very odd - I blame VS for it). I got to say that if I have many exceptions, I would turn this feature off, otherwise this really is a very useful dialog.