# Why is VS 2015 stopping diagnostics session is taking forever?

Tags: c#, wpf, debugging, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to analyze a WPF project (WPF, .NET 4.6.1, EF 6, Moq., on a i5 machine with W10 64 bit) using the performance profiler with only "Timeline" activated.

Problem is that on stopping the program I am stuck in the "Report.....diagsession" tab with the message "Microsoft Visual Studio is stopping your diagnostics session" and the rotating hourglass. Some times it just times out, other times I get to the report eventually, but 5 to 20 minutes later.

Interestingly the time waiting for the diagnostic session to stop is included in the report. It is like the process collecting the data does not get the message to stop recording.

Using Windows Resource Monitor I have noticed VsStandardCollector.exe writing huge amounts of data to a subfolder in "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Temp\". About 9 Gigabyte in my last try, covering 10 minutes in total while my application only ran for 30 seconds before I stopped it.

Anyone with an idea what could cause the delay in stopping the session?

CPU and disk use is very low during waiting (< 5%)

Comment: @DmitrySavy: I am using the performance profiler on purpose to see which WPF visuals eat my CPU. I don't want to disable it, I want to use it.

Comment: @Daniel Hillebrand, so you use the Application Timeline tool under Debug->Performance Profiler..., am I right? If so, do you change the Target from Debug to release mode? Please also clean up previous report files in your project folder, or copy them to other folder before you delete them, and then clean and build your app, re-profile it again.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT Exactly, that is the tool I am using. I just tried again. Ran my app in the performance profiler for 30 seconds, stopped it, and I am still waiting for VS stopping the session.

Comment: @Daniel Hillebrand, Does it still spend 5~20 mins even if in release mode? I just use the default VS settings(C# General), if possible, you could reset your VS settings, and then check the result. If I profile a simple WPF app, it also shared the warning "Microsoft Visual Studio is stopping your diagnostics session", but it just spends several seconds, how about a simple new WPF app?

Comment: @Daniel Hillebrand, if you use the performance profiler, it was used in release mode,  I also suggest you disable "Enable Diagnostics Tools while debugging" which was running atomically during you debug your app, at least, we could make sure that whether this tool impacts your profiler tools. Please also not select the "Enable IntelliTrace" under TOOLS->Options, and disable the Host process in project property.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT,I tried what you suggested, but problem still the same. I even tried with a freshly installed VS 2017 Enterprise and a virgin WPF project created from the template. Still same problem. It seems there is an issue with my OS installation or a component that is used by VS to perform the perfomance profiling.

Comment: @Daniel Hillebrand, if a simple WPF app still has this issue, I also feel that it is the Environment issue, did you install certain third party tools like anti-virus software or others, please close them, test it again. Maybe we would think about the windows configurations or others.

Comment: Vaguely related (an acknowledged performance bug in Visual Studio): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40471914/visual-studio-2015-takes-a-long-time-10-15-minutes-to-reload-projects-after

Comment: Are there any solutions to this problem?

Comment: This is happening to me in VS2019

Answer (score 1):

Recently I've learnt about [PerfView](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/PerfView-Tutorial) tool that is used for performance analysis even inside of Microsoft. It's much cheaper than VisualStudio, in fact it is free.

So you may use it to analyze performance of Visual Studio to answer your question or even better - use it to analyze performance of your own WPF application.

Answer (score 1):

It seems if your project is consumes more than 4 GB, standard profiler is extremely slow and sometimes dead hangs on some unknown invisible internal problem. 
I manage to go through this by steps below

1. Build Release version
2. Run Profiler with State Paused.
3. Give VS give more permissions for you debugging account if VS ask for it.
4. Activate  profiler for short period of time.
5. Close application
6. Wait 10-20 minutes or more to generated report.